# Using OR on WHERE statement in MySql causes slow excecution

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

The following query takes mysql to execute almost 7 times longer than implementing the same using two separate queries, and avoiding OR on the WHERE statement. I prefer using a single query as I can sort and group everything.

Here is the problematic query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT  *
    FROM  `posts`
    LEFT JOIN  `teams_users`
               ON (teams_users.team_id=posts.team_id
              AND  teams_users.user_id='7135')
    WHERE  (teams_users.status='1'
              OR  posts.user_id='7135');
```

Result:

```
id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra 
1 SIMPLE  posts       ALL    user_id NULL NULL NULL 169642 
1 SIMPLE  teams_users eq_ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 8 posts.team_id,const 1 Using where
```

Now if I do the following two queries instead, the aggregate execution time, as said, is shorter by 7 times:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT  *
    FROM  `posts`
    LEFT JOIN  `teams_users`
               ON (teams_users.team_id=posts.team_id
              AND  teams_users.user_id='7135')
    WHERE  (teams_users.status='1');
```

Result:

```
id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 SIMPLE  teams_users ref PRIMARY,status status 1 const 5822 Using where
1 SIMPLE  posts       ref team_id  team_id 5 teams_users.team_id 9 Using where
```

and:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT  *
    FROM  `posts`
    LEFT JOIN  `teams_users`
               ON (teams_users.team_id=posts.team_id
              AND  teams_users.user_id='7135')
    WHERE  (posts.user_id='7135');
```

Result:

```
id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 SIMPLE  posts       ref    user_id user_id 4 const 142 
1 SIMPLE  teams_users eq_ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 8 posts.team_id,const 1
```

Obviously the amount of scanned rows is much lower on the two queries.
Why is the initial query slow?
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, `OR` is frequently a performance-killer.  A common work-around is to do `UNION`.  For your example:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  `posts`
    LEFT JOIN  `teams_users`
               ON (teams_users.team_id=posts.team_id
              AND  teams_users.user_id='7135')
    WHERE  (teams_users.status='1')
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT  *
    FROM  `posts`
    LEFT JOIN  `teams_users`
               ON (teams_users.team_id=posts.team_id
              AND  teams_users.user_id='7135')
    WHERE  (posts.user_id='7135');
```

If you are sure there are not dups, change to the faster `UNION ALL`.

If you are not fishing for missing `team_users` rows, use `JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`.

If you need `ORDER BY`, add some parens:

```
( SELECT ... )
UNION ...
( SELECT ... )
ORDER BY ...
```

Otherwise, the `ORDER BY` would apply only to the second `SELECT`.  (If you also need 'pagination', see [*my blog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination#pagination_and_union) .)

Please note that you might also need `LIMIT` in certain circumstances.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed UNION is much faster than using OR on When statement.

Answer (score 5):

The queries without the `OR` clause are both [*sargable.* That is, they both can be satisfied using indexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

The query with the `OR` would be sargable if the MySQL query planner contained logic to figure out it can rewrite it as the `UNION ALL` of two queries. By the MySQL query planner doesn't (yet) have that kind of logic.

So, it does table scans to get the result set. Those are often very slow.